# Removing package with Chef

Tags: java, package, chef-infra, uninstallation

Can you please tell me, is this possible **to remove Java JDK** package with *Chef*, with `windows_package`, or I have to execute command to silent uninstall? Much better would be the first option.

I've tried this way:

```
windows_package node['name']['JDK1.6'] do
      action            :remove  
end
```

and even added option `installer_type       :custom`, still got this error:

```
FATAL: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: windows_package[Java(TM) SE Development Kit 6 Update 35] (line 4) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0, 42, 127], but received '1603'
---- Begin output of MsiExec.exe /I{32A3A4F4-B792-11D6-A78A-00B0D0160350} /qn ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: 
---- End output of MsiExec.exe /I{32A3A4F4-B792-11D6-A78A-00B0D0160350} /qn ----
Ran MsiExec.exe /I{32A3A4F4-B792-11D6-A78A-00B0D0160350} /qn returned 1603
```

Well, I am out of ideas. On [official Opscode site](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/windows#windows_package) I've found this information:

`:remove: remove a package. The remove action is completely hit or miss as many application uninstallers do not support a full silent/quiet mode.`

But as far as I know, JDK supports silent uninstall.

So - how should I do this in order to properly uninstall packages? Is this even possible?

Many thanks for every help.

---

**Specification:**

- Chef 12.4.1
- Windows 7
- Java JDK in versions: 6u35, 7u79, 8u45

---

If you need additional information, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've ended up with my own implementation. For those, who would need this, too:

```
# variable 'code' is for JDK version code from registry.
# Uninstall comand: MsiExec.exe /quiet /X[CODE]
# Codes are in regkey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall. Be aware to check key for JDK, not JRE!

remove_command = "MsiExec.exe /quiet /X#{code}"

execute "Remove JDK from system" do
        command         remove_command
        returns         [0,1605]  # 1605 for non-existing product error
end
```

For example, for JDK 1.6.35 (mentioned in question) code should be

```
code = '{32A3A4F4-B792-11D6-A78A-00B0D0160350}'
```

So it seems like this is different command than used by Chef:

- used by Chef

`MsiExec.exe /I{32A3A4F4-B792-11D6-A78A-00B0D0160350} /qn`

- this command

`MsiExec.exe /quiet /X{32A3A4F4-B792-11D6-A78A-00B0D0160350}`

Maybe somebody will find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it might not be a chef problem as such.  The uninstaller is hitting an error for some reason.  Try googling for "java install error 1603" and you'll see a bunch of posts, including one that's apparently a bug that's currently under investigation https://www.java.com/en/download/help/error_1603.xml - though it sounds like that might be install not uninstall.

Try removing it manually and debug that, then once you understand it you can chef it.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar to your answer, but it only requires the package name rather than the code from the registry.

```
execute 'uninstall_jdk8u72' do
  command "wmic product where name=\"#{node[:java8u72][:package_name]}\" call uninstall"
end
```

I got the idea from https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/windows/issues/89